# MySQL unknown server host (thru ssh tunnel & CLI, but not workbench)

Tags: mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

When I attempt to access mysql over an SSH tunnel, I get the error:

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '[serverhost]' (0)
```

When I make the attempt through MySQL Workbench or over an ordinary SSH CLI, it works fine, though. What am I doing wrong? (I have scanned multiple related threads on this site, but none that explained this behaviour to me.)

**TMI:**

The host I have is a name, not an IP.

I open the tunnel thus:

```
plink.exe [user]@[remote-ip] -P [ssh-port] -pw [pw] -L [local-listen-port]:localhost:[remote-mysql-port]
```

I call mysql on my command line (through tunnel) thus:

```
mysql -h [serverhost] -u [user] -p[pw] --port [local-listen-port]
```

I call mysql over an SSH command line (no tunnel) thus:

```
mysql -h [serverhost] -u [user] -p[pw] --port [remote-mysql-port]
```

Comment: Get rid of the square brackets.

Comment: @Pekka, the brackets are only there to indicate an editor's note, a replacement of my actual code with a representation of it. I didn't really type them any more than I used "local-listen-port" as a port number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing plink command is wrong, as its specifying localhost as the destination address (which is the localhost on the other side of the SSH session, so [remote-ip], by your reckoning, which is why you are getting an error) - it should be [serverhost].

Then, you are then *mistakenly* attempting to connect mysql directly to [serverhost], but the tunnel does not affect routing, so that is incorrect, you should be connecting to localhost.

Your existing example command works when connected to an ssh shell session on [remote-ip], because you are connecting *from* [remote-ip], which has access to [serverhost] presumably.

Assuming [serverhost] is the remote server, your commands should be:

```
plink.exe [user]@[remote-ip] -P [ssh-port] -pw [pw] -L [local-listen-port]:[serverhost]:[remote-mysql-port]
```

Then

```
mysql -h localhost -u [user] -p[pw] --port [local-listen-port]
```

EDIT: Let me try and diagram it for you, since you are obviously misunderstanding the nature of the tunnel:

The SSH connection

> localhost[?] <--------> remote-ip[22]

The tunnel

> localhost[local-port] <---- SSH ---> remote-ip[22] <--- TCP --->
>   serverhost[remote-port]

Therefore, SSH/plink has bound a port on localhost, using the [local-port] number you have specified, that, when receiving a connection request, establishes a connection from [remote-ip] to [serverhost:remote-port], then shuffles the sends/receives back and forth between them, using its own SSH connection for the hop from [localhost] to [remote-ip].

So - once the tunnel has been set up, to access [serverhost:remote-port], you actually point your tools at [localhost:local-port], and the tunnel routes the traffic to the appropriate place.

Comment: I may not understand your response, but did you notice that the host needs to be given even when I'm just ssh-ing or using workbench? I'm not trying to use 'host' to refer to the computer on the other end of the tunnel but to a mysql server which is somehow distinct from that computer.

Comment: Removing mention of the host or swapping it for 'localhost' gives me `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 0`. Again, I would stress, that I supply the same information through Workbench and somehow succeed in accessing the server.

Comment: Yes, I was pointing out that the [serverhost] is the full domain name of the host on which the server exists, the one you are creating the ssh tunnel to - but the ssh tunnel creates a local port, on your localhost machine, that links to that port when you connect - so to connect, you use: mysql -h localhost -u [user] -p[pw] --port [local-listen-port]

Comment: But even if I ssh to the remote machine specified by 'remote-ip' (laying aside tunnels), the host isn't localhost. It therefore can't be localhost when I'm running through a tunnel to that computer. In my case, the mysql server is not local to the destination of my SSH tunnel.

Comment: That's why I supplied my "call mysql over an SSH command line" above. Even there, I have to specify a foreign hostname.

Comment: No, but the tunnel end point you are connecting to IS.  When creating an SSH forward tunnel, the local end point is always the local machine you execute the command on, the other end of the tunnel is established from the other end of the SSH connection, to wherever you specify (assuming the machine at the other end can reach it).

Comment: Your machine is A, remote SSH server is B, mysql server is C.  SSH tunnel goes from A ----> B, SSH tunnel binds to local port on A, when it receives a connection, it connects to remote port specified on C, tunneling any information sent or received across the SSH tunnel first, and then on/from B to C.

Comment: If your understanding of the situation is accurate, why does your prescription return the error mentioned above, whereas my access over SSH (sans tunnel) work correctly?

Comment: have you tried the adjusted tunnel change I edited into the answer?  your error response pre-dates that.

Comment: I assume by the lack of response you have not - and instead have generously downvoted a full description of what you are doing wrong... ho hum.

Comment: I do apologize for my conduct. I was called away. (My erroneous downvote was cast early in our intercourse.)

Comment: Thanks for your patience with me.